# Getting tons of javascript errors in IE10, but no other browser

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, internet-explorer

I have been developing an ASP.NET web application on a computer with Windows 7. I have been testing on Firefox, Chrome and IE 7 and 8 using IE tester and IE 9 natively. All has been well. Today I got a new notebook with Windows 8 and IE 10 and am getting tons of javascipt errors. If I run it in IE 9 compatability mode via the developer console it works fine. Why is  it working in every browser except IE 10? Is this a common issue? If it matters it seems to be an issue when both jQuery and the ASP.NET server control http://www.basicdatepicker.com/ which appears to use this javascript library: http://www.datejs.com/ are on the same page being rendered.

I've been looking around the net and have noticed there are sites that says javascript is not enabled when I view them in IE 10. For example:

https://time.manpowerdirect.com/Individual/TermsOfUse.aspx

[image]

Accoding to my security settings javascript is enabled:

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on or why this is happening?

Comment: *"Is this a common issue?"* Yes, it is. Wherever I've worked we've always had to maintain `N + 1` javascript codebases, where `N` is the amount of IE versions around since (and including) IE 7. There are just too many ways its javascript handling changes between versions.

Comment: No, we support old IE and we only have a single, clean, codebase. You just have to be careful and it's time consuming. IE10 usually plays nice though, post the errors you're getting.

Comment: I don't generally have problems developing with IE10 on my Win8 machine. Could it be a problem with browser capabilities detection in your setup not recognizing a new browser version?

Comment: Common?  Not sure.  Have I seen it?  Yup.  The codebase I just inherited breaks all over in IE 10.

Comment: What version of .NET framework does your ASP.NET site uses?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE10 SCRIPT5009: '\_\_doPostBack' is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273618/ie10-script5009-dopostback-is-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install ASP.NET hotfixes on the server to update its browser definition files such that it recognizes that IE10 is a browser that supports JavaScript. Please see the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273618/ie10-script5009-dopostback-is-undefined).

Comment: +1, I've seen this too. On our sites postbacks worked in all browsers except IE10.