# Cookieless Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-11

Recently some users have updated to Internet Explorer 11. There now appear to be some issues with Internet Explorer not accepting cookies and switching to a cookie less authentication.  This causes a `NullReferenceException`.

Is there a way to force IE to accept cookies? I have full access to the PC and I do not seem to have any problems with other websites.

Comment: Your ASP.NET is not patched. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3e9f3c92-8724-4f41-9be3-34c2877ada0f/ie11-session-id-in-url

> Microsoft have changed the user agent string for IE and as a result
>   it's not longer detected as IE.
>
> In the meantime, you can change the default behaviour by editing your
>   web.config. Rather than setting cookie handling in the sessionState
>   you should do it in the `<authentication>` section.
>
> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>   <forms loginUrl="~/YourLoginUrl" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
> </authentication>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [long standing IE11 problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3e9f3c92-8724-4f41-9be3-34c2877ada0f/ie11-session-id-in-url).

There is a settings option for the page to accept cookies, or alternately, recommendations seem to include changing your web.config to handle cookies seperately. To source Firefly's code in the above link:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/YourLoginUrl" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

should be enough to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, IE11 issue seems creepy !! But anyways I think they won't feel happy until they torture us.

In my case, we had an old legacy application on .Net framework 4 *(is that really old hmmm ?! LoL)* which stopped working and started producing cookieless session issues and "__doPostBack is undefined" in IE11.

Tried installing updates on server for .Net Framework 4 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39257 but did not work.

Thankfully then read this post [__doPostBack is undefined in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915720/dopostback-is-undefined-in-ie11) and installed .Net Framework 4.5 on server from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30653 to resolve issue.