# IE11 - Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference

Tags: asp.net, telerik, internet-explorer-11, scriptmanager

I have a asp.net web page with *radgrid* and *radajaxmanager* are used in it.

It works as expected on all browsers other than **IE11**

When I click on button I got this error on my Console.

```
Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference
```

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11 this should solve your problem. It's a .NET 4 issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420756/23562) for more details or [a post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) by Scott Hanselman detailing the problem. Core of the problem is outdated browser detection files on the server such that IE11 is an unknown browser (and therefore lacking Javascript support according to the server).